# Can't Get $expand Working for a Single OData Entity With AsyncEntitySetController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, odata

I am unable to use $expand on a single entity, but it works fine on a collection. I have the following asynchronous OData Web API controller:

```
public class AuthorController : AsyncEntitySetController<Author, int>
{
    private readonly IAuthorRepository _AuthorRepo = new AuthorRepository();

    // GET odata/<controller>
    [Queryable]
    public override async Task<IEnumerable<Author>> Get()
    {
        var authors = await _AuthorRepo.GetAll();
        return authors.AsQueryable();
    }

    // GET odata/<controller>/5
    [Queryable]
    public async Task<Author> Get([FromODataUri]int key)
    {
        var author = await _AuthorRepo.GetById(key);
        return author;
    }
}
```

Requesting the collection via https://api.acme.org/odata/Authors works, and so does expanding the authors' books via https://api.acme.org/odata/Authors?$expand=Books.

However, attempting to expand a single entity using the Get method above that accepts a key parameter via https://api.acme.org/odata/Authors(1)?$expand=Books yields the following error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:   Get on type
>   AcmeApi.Controllers.AuthorsController  Get on type
>   AcmeApi.Controllers.AuthorssController

Upon reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128009/web-api-odata-how-do-you-expand-on-a-single-entity), I tried returning a SingleResult by updating my second Get method to:

```
[Queryable]
public SingleResult<Account> Get([FromODataUri]int key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create<Account>(m_AccountRepo.GetById(key));
}
```

But this results in the following compilation error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'

The asynchronous GetById repository method is:

```
public async Task<Author> GetById(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => _Authors.Where(a => a.Id == id).SingleOrDefault());
}
```

If returning a SingleResult is the way to get $expand to work for a single entity, what is the correct way to do so from an asynchronous controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `Get([FromOdataUri]int key)` to `GetAuthor([]int)` may resolve this issue.
 
Please refer this post: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions.